# Why does ace editor load with all text highlighted and how to remove it?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ace-editor

My code looks like :

```
$scope.aceIDEs='var hw = new function() {\n  console.log("Hello world!");\n}'

$scope.loadAceJSExample = function (_editor) {
_editor.setValue($scope.aceIDEs);
_editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
_editor.setHighlightActiveLine(true);
};
```

And:

```
<div class="container fade-in" style='padding: 4em;'>
<div>
      ui-ace="{onLoad : loadAceJSExample,
      onChange : aceJSExampleChanged,
      useWrapMode : true,
      theme : 'github',
      showGutter: true,
      mode: 'javascript'

    }" />
```

I tried calling     _editor.getSession().removeMarker(); but did not help

Every time i refresh it looks like this,once i click in it returns to normal:
[image: Before i click]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `_editor.session.setValue($scope.aceIDEs);` which also resets undomanager.
Alternatively you can use `_editor.setValue($scope.aceIDEs, cursorPos);`. where `cursorPos=-1` puts cursor at start and `cursorPos=1` at the end.
Or call `_editor.clearSelection()` after setting value.

Comment: _editor.session.setValue($scope.aceIDEs); thank you.