# How to remove highlighting in ace editor using jQuery

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am using the ace editor and wanted to highlight a row using the line number. I got the following code to do it

```
var Range = require('ace/range').Range
MyObjs.editor1.session.addMarker(new Range(11, 0, 11, 1), "myMarker", "fullLine");
```

It works fine. But when I reload the editor or reinitialize it, this doesn't remove the highlighting part.

Even if I reset the editor contents using the `setValue()` Api, it still retains the highlighting.

I am unable to remove the highlighting part using jquery.

Even the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22039568/why-does-ace-editor-load-with-all-text-highlighted-and-how-to-remove-it?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), using angular Js isn't working for me.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `session.removeMarker` method to remove the marker

```
 var markerId = MyObjs.editor1.session.addMarker(...);
 MyObjs.editor1.session.removeMarker(markerId)
```